# Multiple GCR Project Registry Login in Jenkins Machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

We have our cloud setup on GCP with multiple projects. In our Jenkins machines, I can see multiple entries of docker registries. One of them is something like this:-

```
"https://gcr.io/abc-defghi-212121": {
                    "auth": "somethingsomethingsomething=",
                    "email": "not@val.id"
```

I want to do same thing for another project which will be like:-

```
"https://gcr.io/jkl-mnopqr-313131": {
                    "auth": "somethingsomethingsomething=",
                    "email": "not@val.id"
```

So that if I do docker login to both registries it should work. I have followed below links:-
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

there are different methods in this but still confused. Please help.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to pull or push an image to the container registry?  The link you have followed is about how you can configure authentication to the container registry. Are you trying to configure the Docker to use gcloud as a credential helper?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Yes we are trying to pull and push images from jenkins CI and we have a single machine and multiple registries in different projects. Yes,  trying to configure the Docker to use gcloud as a credential helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common authentication method to use docker with container registry is using gcloud as a Docker credential helper. This [authentication method](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#before_you_begin) is performed by running:
$ gcloud auth configure-docker

This will create a json file, ~/.docker/config.json, that will "tell" docker to authenticate in container registry using the gcloud current user.

However, I am assuming in your case it's Jenkins that builds and pushes your images to the container registry. You need to authenticate it, which I believe it's performed using the [OAuth plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+OAuth+Plugin). You can find it in the Jenkins interface:
Jenkins -> Credentials -> Global Credentials -> Add Credentials

Nevertheless, you could also refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting) documentation where explained how to troubleshoot common Container Registry and Docker issues. Also, make sure that you have the [required permission](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) to push or pull.